# Pandas output to json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, output

I am trying to export this DF into my desired output:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'V':  ["0","0","0","0","0","0"],
        'A': ["1","0","1","1","1","0"],
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['V','A'])
```

Desired Output:

```
{"0": {"V": 0,
       "A": 1,
      },
 "1": {"V": 0,
       "A": 0,
     },
...
}
```

Exporting it as json doesn't have the same form.

```
df= df.to_json(orient="table")
with open('df.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient=index`:

```
In [1672]: x = df.to_dict('index')

In [1672]: x
Out[1672]: 
{0: {'V': '0', 'A': '1'},
 1: {'V': '0', 'A': '0'},
 2: {'V': '0', 'A': '1'},
 3: {'V': '0', 'A': '1'},
 4: {'V': '0', 'A': '1'},
 5: {'V': '0', 'A': '0'}}
```

For `json` output:

```
In [1676]: import json

In [1679]: y = json.dumps(x)

In [1681]: y
Out[1681]: '{"0": {"V": "0", "A": "1"}, "1": {"V": "0", "A": "0"}, "2": {"V": "0", "A": "1"}, "3": {"V": "0", "A": "1"}, "4": {"V": "0", "A": "1"}, "5": {"V": "0", "A": "0"}}'
```

**EDIT:** To convert values into `int`, do this:

```
In [1672]: x = df.to_dict('index')
In [1708]: x = {k: {kk: int(vv) for kk, vv in v.items()} for k, v in x.items()}

In [1710]: y = json.dumps(y)

In [1711]: y
Out[1711]: '{"0": {"V": 0, "A": 1}, "1": {"V": 0, "A": 0}, "2": {"V": 0, "A": 1}, "3": {"V": 0, "A": 1}, "4": {"V": 0, "A": 1}, "5": {"V": 0, "A": 0}}'
```

Comment: Perfect! I just need to convert the numbers then. Thank you :)

Comment: Great. Do you need help with that as well?

Comment: You're welcome. I've anyway updated my answer to convert it into `int` for the sake of completion.